# Running a compiled Jar file in Jenkins

Tags: java, git, jar, jenkins

I am trying to run an executable jar file through jenkins. What I am trying to achieve here is I have an executable jar file created and is residing locally in my machine. I want to put it in Git and then run it in jenkins. Is there some how I can do this? I am totally new to Jenkins and if someone can help it will save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do nearly everything you want with Jenkins since you can have it run arbitrary scripts / executables.

If you want to put this .jar in git, then the Jenkins jobs will retrieve it when it fetches the repo. Then you just need to add a script shell step to the build, and to put your command line `java my.jar my.class ....`

On the other hand, it's sometimes [frowned up](https://robinwinslow.co.uk/2013/06/11/dont-ever-commit-binary-files-to-git/) to put binary files in git. It's true in particular if the .jar will need to be often updated. Hence you might want to provide the .jar to the Jenkins job using alternative methods. For example using a maven repository.

Comment: This was an excellent solution. Can we run as a windows batch command? The jenkins is deployed in a remote server and i am running jenkins from Mac machine. Instead of execute shell there is run as  windows batch command? What would be the script for it

Comment: If Jenkins is installed on a Windows server, yes you can. Instead of selecting a "script shell step", you should be able to select a "windows batch step", and you can paste the content of a Windows batch script there.